# Need to produce two records from a single record in spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a file which contains below records.

```
cardno1,cardno2,age,name,address,ssn
cardno1,       ,age,name,address,ssn
cardno2,       ,age,name,address,ssn
```

I have to parse this file and need to produce 2 records whenever both cardno1 and cardno2 are coming in the input.
example:- cardno1,cardno2,age,name,address,ssn

```
In this case two records are needed as below
```

cardno1,age,name,address,ssn

cardno2,age,name,address,ssn

```
How this can be achieved using spark java.
Need help to solve this.
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page and edit your question to improve it. Good questions tend to receive quick, better answers from the community.

Comment: fixed record structure? positional dependencies? splitting considerations made?

Comment: if the fields are all the same, then recs 2 and 3 are superfluous

Comment: Updated answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scala - not a JAVA Spark person, not a good thing imho - so you can convert, using RDD and DF. Using DF can get better per line output. Not so hard to convert, but in Notebooks Java not common.

Input

```
cardno1,cardno2,age,name,address,ssn
cardno1,,age,name,address,ssn
cardno2,,age,name,address,ssn
cardno3,,age,name,address,ssn
cardno4,cardno5,age2,name2,address2,ssn2
cardno4,,age2,name2,address2,ssn2
cardno5,,age2,name2,address2,ssn2
```

Code

```
val filesRDD = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/so.txt",5) 
val linesRDD = filesRDD.map(_.split(",")).filter(c => !"".equalsIgnoreCase(c(1).trim)).map(entries=> (entries(0),entries(1),entries(2),entries(3),entries(4),entries(5)))
val linesRDD2_first = linesRDD.map { case (v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6) => (v1, v3, v4, v5, v6) }
val linesRDD2_second = linesRDD.map { case (v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6) => (v2, v3, v4, v5, v6) }
val df1 = linesRDD2_first.toDF()
val df2 = linesRDD2_second.toDF()
val df3 = df1.union(df2).toDF("cardno", "age", "name", "address", "ssn")
df3.show(false)
```

Output in Dataframe format

```
+-------+----+-----+--------+----+
|cardno |age |name |address |ssn |
+-------+----+-----+--------+----+
|cardno1|age |name |address |ssn |
|cardno4|age2|name2|address2|ssn2|
|cardno2|age |name |address |ssn |
|cardno5|age2|name2|address2|ssn2|
+-------+----+-----+--------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.My requirement here is to produce two records from a single record where both card numbers (cardno1 and cardno2) are present. so for the record:- cardno1,cardno2,age,name,address,ssn it should out put 2 records like cardno1,age,name,address,ssn and cardno2,age,name,address,ssn

Comment: Currently I am reading this file using spark  and parsing it using java pojo class.here I am using map function.But with map function can give only one output.Here my requirement is to produce two output records from a single record whenever we have both card numbers present in the input. Please explain me the logic to achieve /solve this requirement.

Comment: al linesRDD = filesRDD.map(_.split(",")).filter(c => !"".equalsIgnoreCase(c(1).trim)).map(entries=> (entries(0),entries(1),entries(2),entries(3),entries(4),entries(5)))
val linesRDD2_first = linesRDD.map { case (v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6) => (v1, v3, v4, v5, v6) }
val linesRDD2_second = linesRDD.map { case (v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6) => (v2, v3, v4, v5, v6) }  .Could you please explain these lines of code.I am new to scala programing.

Comment: In this small space one cannot do a complete intro into Spark. Try this https://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2015/12/14/spark-scala-tutorial.html